# Two figures side by side - caption

Tags: floats, captions, floatrow

I have two figures side by side in my work and I need to add captions to them. However when I add captions they are not in line with the figures. Is anyone able to help me? Thank you very much.

This is the code:

```
 \begin{figure}[h]
           \begin{floatrow}
             \ffigbox{\includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{Figures/dontknow_ecb_countries_members}}{\caption{\small{The level of people\\not expressing the\\opinion on trust in\\the ECB in individual\\Euro-Area countries}}\label{fig:dont know countries members}}
             \ffigbox{\includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{Figures/trust_ecb_countries_nonmembers}}{\caption{\small{The trust in the ECB\\in individual non-Euro\\Area countries}}\label{fig:trust countries nonmembers}}
           \end{floatrow}
        \end{figure}
```

And this is what I get:

[image: The result]

Answer (score 1):

Use `\ffigbox[\FBwidth]` so that the caption hets the same width as the picture. BTW, you can't use `\\` inside `\caption`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[h]
           \begin{floatrow}
             \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.2]{example-image}}
                               {\caption{The level of people not expressing the opinion on trust in the ECB in individual Euro-Area countries}\label{fig:dont know countries members}}
             \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.2]{example-image-a}}
                               {\caption{The trust in the ECB in individual non-Euro Area countries}\label{fig:trust countries nonmembers}}
           \end{floatrow}
        \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can replace `\\`with  `\endgraf`, though.